Cauchy sequence of symmetric difference of sets converges in measure

Complete mesurable space, $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N>0$ s.t. $\forall m,n>N,$ we have $\mu(E_m\Delta E_n)<\epsilon$.
WTS: $\exists E$ s.t. $\mu(E\Delta E_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$

$L_1$ is complete and $\mu(A\Delta B)\equiv||\chi_A-\chi_B||_1$ then we may conclude the result. However I want to show directly, without resorting to $L_1$ space, that $E_n\rightarrow E$ in $\mu$ where $E:=\liminf_n(E_n)\equiv\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\bigcap_{j\geq i}E_j\equiv${$x$: $x\in E_n$ $\textit{eventually}$}.
$\textit{Attempt:}$ $A\Delta B=A\backslash B\cup B\backslash A\implies\mu(A\Delta B)\leq\mu(A\backslash B)+\mu(B\backslash A)$.
WTS: $\mu(E\backslash E_n)\rightarrow0$ and $\mu(E_n\backslash E)\rightarrow0$.
The first one is a direct result of the definition of $E$ and Cauchy. Since $\exists m$ large enough s.t. $E\subset E_m$, we have $\mu(E\backslash E_n)\leq\mu(E_m\backslash E_n)\leq\mu(E_m\Delta E_n)\rightarrow0$.
However, I'm stuck with showing the second convergence. Any idea on how to proceed with this or other approach that doesn't invoke the completeness of $L_1$? Thanks in advance.

$\liminf_n E_n$ doesn't work. Given $n$ write it uniquely as $2^k+l$ where $0\leq l<2^k$, and let $E_n$ be the unit interval $[0,1]$ with $\left[\frac{l}{2^k},\frac{l+1}{2^k}\right]$ removed. Then the $E_n$'s converge to $[0,1]$ but $\liminf_n E_n=\emptyset$ because every point is missing infinitely often. For similar reason $\limsup_n E_n$ doesn't work.
On the other hand, this does work if you choose a subsequence that converges "faster". See the answer to this question. I would say it's not much different from the proof of completeness of $L^1$, though.

Very inspiring, thank you. The indexing is a bit unclear but I get the gist. This construction also reminds me of the "wandering blocks" counterexample. I'll take a closer look later.
